# Does it make any sense to use R^2 as a measurment

Tags: r-squared

I was wondering whether it makes any sense to use R-squared for the graph/model. I think it is not since it does not clearly explain a linear relation.
[image: Time series xt]

Comment: Is that a time series?

Comment: $R^2$ does not necessarily explain a *linear* relationship. It assesses how well a model fits to data: [R-squared is equal to 81% means what?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/478657/1352)

Comment: Could you please clarify what "use $R^2$" might mean in this setting?